# Pass array as a command line argument to Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, command-line-arguments

Need to pass array as a command line argument to Asp.Net Core hosted service.

Added providers

```
config
  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
  .AddCommandLine(args);
```

somewhere in application I have

```
var actions = _configuration.GetSection("actions").Get<List<string>>();
foreach (var action in actions)
{
   Console.WriteLine(action);
}
```

Try to run app like

```
dotnet MyService.dll --actions Action1,Action2
dotnet MyService.dll --actions [Action1,Action2]
dotnet MyService.dll --actions ["Action1","Action2"]
```

but no results, the `actions` is `null`

When I add `"actions": ["Action1","Action2"]` to appsettings.json then binding works well.

How to pass array as a command line argument?

I can get it in this way `_configuration.GetValue<string>("actions").Split(",");`, but how to bind it to list?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ASP.NET Core configuration is a set of key-value pairs. The appsettings.json property you've shown gets converted into the following:

- actions:0 = Action1
- actions:1 = Action2

Provide this same set of key-value pairs as multiple command-line arguments to get the desired result:

```
dotnet MyService.dll --actions:0 Action1 --actions:1 Action2
```

Comment: A bit more details from the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#command-line-arguments